# Cannot assign value of type 'Character' to type 'String?'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have run into this problem where when I tried to add [indexPath.row] either one of my cells it would give me this error and I don't know what is causing it. I have researched this problem but no-one had the solution to it.

I'm just trying to pass data from the ViewController to the TableViewController and create a new cell every time more info has been added instead of editing the first one

TableViewController:[TableViewController with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnf2x.png)

ViewController:[ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H07Hw.png)

Comment: Please post code and errors as text in your question. Pictures can't be searched or referenced.

Comment: Yes, add code here not in an image. People can help you much easier and quicker

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you declare `recievingAmmount` and `recievingPrice` as strings not an array , you need

```
var recievingAmmount = [String]()
var recievingPrice = [String]()
```

Also it's better to combine them in a model like

```
struct Item {
  var amount:String
  var price:String
}
```

And do

```
var arr = [Item]()
```

Comment: should i use the struct in the ViewController or in the TableView?